Nodemcu ESP32s and SPI ST7789V2 display not working
I have been trying to get a display from waveshare working with NodeMCU ESP32S. The display says 1.69inch LCD, 240 x 280 pixels, ST778V2. Searching on the internet results with article leading to ST7789 only. This display has a weird pinout as well which is similar to ST7735. Below are the pins that I have.
VCC, GND, DIN, CLK,CS,DC,RST and BLK. I have tried  Adafruit_ST7789 and TFT_ESPI library with different variations of code and connections but none seems to work. Below is one of the code.
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_ST7789.h>
#include <SPI.h>

// Define pins for ESP32
#define TFT_CS     15
#define TFT_RST    2
#define TFT_DC     17

// Create an instance of Adafruit_ST7789
Adafruit_ST7789 tft = Adafruit_ST7789(TFT_CS, TFT_DC, TFT_RST);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Initialize display
  tft.init(240, 280); // Initialize ST7789 with a pixel width of 240 and height of 240

  // Fill the screen with black color
  tft.fillScreen(ST77XX_BLACK);

  // Set text color to white
  tft.setTextColor(ST77XX_WHITE);

  // Set text size
  tft.setTextSize(2);

  // Set cursor position
  tft.setCursor(0, 0);

  // Display "Hello, World!"
  tft.println("Hello, World!");
}

void loop() {
  // Nothing here for a static display
}

I am in dire need to help on this one. It has been 2days I am trying this but the information about this V2 display is limited. Please be nice, I am just a beginner in all this.
Below are the pin connections and diagram.



ESP32 Pin
ST7789V2 pin




GPIO13
DIN


GPIO14
CLK


GPIO15
CS


GPIO17
DC


GPIO2
RST


3V3
BL


5V
VCC


GND
GND





Did you try the examples provided by Waveshare? https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/1.69inch_LCD_Module

After tinkering some more, I switched to TFT_eSPI library by bodmer. But that may not have solved it for me. What worked was connecting VCC to 3.3v and BL pin to 5V pins. This is weird as the spec says it works on 5V too but it works now and I am able to display things on the display.

Keep in mind to restart the ESP32 if you change the connections when
ESP32 is powered on.


The Waveshare documentation for this module states in big bold red “Please ensure that the power supply voltage and logic voltage are the same, otherwise it will not work properly”. As all other signals are 3.3V you indeed have to power it with 3.3V as well. The backlight is separate so you can provide a different voltage there.

@jcaron Thanks for pointing that out. For me, the BL pin does not necessarily have to be connected at all. It just works with VCC - 3.3V. There is no effect on the brightness or operation of the display if I keep the BL disconnected, which does seem off from the documentation.
